# What is the difference between code reuse and software product line engineering?

Tags: project-management, computer-science, software

What is the difference between code reuse and software product line engineering?

Why is simple code reuse not successful enough?

Comment: Have you defined these terms? If so, share the definitions so we don't have to make any assumptions .

Answer (score 7):

A simple google search turns up this definition:

> The characteristic that distinguishes software product lines from previous efforts is predictive versus opportunistic software reuse. Rather than put general software components into a library in hopes that opportunities for reuse will arise, software product lines only call for software artifacts to be created when reuse is predicted in one or more products in a well defined product line.
>
> [Software Development Magazine - Project Management, Programming, Software Testing](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=45)

Which is trying to say something like: intentionally designing a new ribbon control that can be used by all MS Office products is a little different than reusing the String class.

Seems like a line that would be easy to blur.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest answer is design is a forward process - the software design process - and code reuse is a backwards process.

I tried to find all the things I needed inside a graphics code base, and then 1000 software code bases later I had to concede there was no simple way to find what I needed.

So I wrote a book to explain it:

[Untrapped Value 1.01](https://leanpub.com/untrappedvalue101/embed)

There's lots to explain, and rationalize, and little room to cover it all.

Here's a simple dimension to consider: many people that write code come from many viewpoints and expertises like mathematics. If you are a biologist writing a math function for exponential decay or growth you may or may not include all the things you should if you aren't an expert at that math, you don't think it's important.
A mathematician that wrote his Ph.D. thesis on exponential functions would wonder where all the supporting things he feels you need to do the same work. Testing, proofs, sanity checks, and math error exception callbacks. It's all about humans looking back at work they weren't there at the point it was written.

The single biggest shock I found, time and again, was how many people didn't think to go and find an open source software project that did the math first, tested all conditions, and was complete with testing to prove it works. Most people just make their own version. Most people don't know the libc library does so many functions that in their ignorance they end up duplicating.

So, rather than expanding on successful math, most people make a one-time source work, and then move on.

Software design, by the spiral design model, the waterfall model, and on and on starts at the beginning with requirements and ends in product specifications. You have things you want to make and you quickly find software that helps you get there, normally in a hurry and without a lot of interest in documenting, just getting it working.

Software reuse, which I call the process of untrapping value, is the process of starting at the end of another's work. Maybe the product was discontinued or companies merged. Maybe the scientist was good at proposals and bad at software. Maybe they rushed it over the weekend. You can't get the spirit of the work because you weren't in the room, you might not have been on the same continent when it was written.

It's sad when you think about it. You have code from NASA, Universities, and even code on the Joint Strike Fighter that can't be completely covered. There are millions of engineers and scientists that would love to contribute but the knowledge overhead to understand what's written and help is daunting.